# I am new at programming im trying to install react

Tags: reactjs

4 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

I am getting this error may you please help

Comment: Ignore warnings..

Comment: npm output for installing packages is quite verbose and is known to show a lot of security warnings.  (Which begs the question - why can't the folks deploying these tools and packages fix these issues for us?)  For learning purposes, you can ignore these warnings.  Come back to those security issues when you are ready to ship.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error.it is just a warning, you can do `npm audit fix`, refer [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit) for more